# Banner header CSS is missing

Tags: html, css

I wanted to make a HTML page with some background color in header with some text. I wanted exactly like this but I am not getting CSS for this particular class `w3-container w3-teal`.

Can anybody tell how to get the CSS of these class.

Here is a link from where I am taking.
https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryit.asp?filename=tryw3css_containers_div_header

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>W3.CSS</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<body>

<div class="w3-container w3-teal">
  <h1>Header</h1>
</div>

<div class="w3-container">
  <p>The w3-container class can be used to display headers.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Link is broken. Also those w3schools even allow you to hotlink their css?

Comment: Your example should work well. You need to check does `w3.css` file is loaded for you or not.

Comment: Just noticed that you have missed `head` tag if it makes sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is the css:**

```
.w3-teal{    background-color: #009688; color:#fff;}
```

> Here is the working code:

```css
.w3-container, .w3-panel {
    padding: 0.01em 16px;
}
.w3-teal, .w3-hover-teal:hover {
    color: #fff!important;
    background-color: #009688!important;
}
```

```html
<div class="w3-container w3-teal">
  <h1>Header</h1>
</div>

<div class="w3-container">
  <p>The w3-container class can be used to display headers.</p>
</div>
```

**Template 2 :**

```js
$('.ToggleDiv').click(function() {
  $('.menu').slideToggle(500);
});
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

.w3-container,
.w3-panel {
  padding: 0.01em 16px;
}

.w3-teal,
.w3-hover-teal:hover {
  color: #fff!important;
  background-color: #009688!important;
}

.ToggleDiv {
  position: absolute;
  top: 33px;
  right: 40px;
  z-index: 999;
  font-size: 28px;
}

.ToggleDiv a {
  color: #fff
}

h1 {
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.menu {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  top: 83px;
  background: #fff;
  display: none;
  color: #000;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="w3-container w3-teal">
  <h1>Header</h1>
  <div class="ToggleDiv"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
  </div>
  <div class="menu">
    <p>Helo I am being shown !!!</p>
    <p>Helo I am being shown !!!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Also OP is missing the `head` tag.

Comment: @Sahil Thanks for answer. It works.. Is there any wahy I can make use of arrow in right and can open close on click.

Comment: What do you want to open close on click?

Comment: Question answer.. . Probably I will use this... https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryit.asp?filename=tryw3css_accordion  lass="w3-btn w3-block w3-black w3-left-align" and "w3-container w3-hide" I need css.. Shall I ask in different question. ?

Comment: you want this template now with click functionality?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142279/discussion-between-sahil-dhir-and-david).